# ssis execute package task showing as red, but child packages showing all green

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis, etl

When running a package that contains multiple 'execute package tasks' the 'child' packages are automatically opened in vs.net (BIDS).

All of the tasks in both of the first two (child) packages turn green i.e. success

So why is the parent package showing red tasks (and then the whole thing grinds to a halt)

?

Comment: Have you checked to see if any components failed in the post execution of the child packages?  This would cause all the control flow components to complete successfully and the child package still fail.

Comment: What does VS show in the Execution Results/Output window? If you have logging turned on, and you should, what does your log indicate for the OnError and OnTaskFailed events?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone following this thread: @DavidBenham has shared good advice--that is to enable logging. Short of that, since it sounds like you are debugging the package through the IDE, you can disable/enable the components called. This would allow you to look at specific flows until you isolate the problem.